# Ubuntu's file path

Tags: filesystem

../ is to jump from my Index.html to Home. [Home>Programming>index.html]

In home there is Programmig & Pictures folders. The screenshot I want to get is inside Pictures.

My code is in the image. Why cant I get my screenshot with this file path.I'm new user of Ubuntu. How can I do to get my picture with correct file path calling?

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Check if the filename/path is correct. First put the file in the same directory to troubleshoot. This question most likely has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: How is this HTML file served?